# How to send data from php page to nodejs and receive result back?

Tags: php, node.js

My webpage use php. I want to send data to nodejs for handle something then return result back to my php webpage. I did not found any useful example for this yet. Can anyone guide me on this with examples?

Comment: Is the nodejs app a web app running on a web server?

Comment: I removed not so useful sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using cross-origin http requests to communicate between the 2. You can have a look at this [CORS](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) package for Nodejs